# Linux serial port I/O question

Tags: linux, embedded, serial-port

In the following C program for an embedded device, I am trying to display a dot (".") every time a user, on a remote computer connected by a serial cable to my device, enters some characters on her terminal program and hits the ENTER key.

What I am seeing is that once the first carriage return is detected, the printf displays dots in an infinite loop. I was expecting FD_ZERO et FD_CLR to "reset" the wait condition.

How to?

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

main()
{
    int    fd1;       /* Input sources 1 and 2 */
    fd_set readfs;    /* File descriptor set */
    int    maxfd;     /* Maximum file desciptor used */
    int    loop=1;    /* Loop while TRUE */

    /*
       open_input_source opens a device, sets the port correctly, and
       returns a file descriptor.
    */
    fd1 = open("/dev/ttyS2", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);
    if (fd1<0)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    maxfd =fd1+1;  /* Maximum bit entry (fd) to test. */

    /* Loop for input */
    while (loop)
    {
        FD_SET(fd1, &readfs);  /* Set testing for source 1. */

        /* Block until input becomes available. */
        select(maxfd, &readfs, NULL, NULL, NULL);

        if (FD_ISSET(fd1, &readfs))
        {
            /* input from source 1 available */
            printf(".");
            FD_CLR(fd1, &readfs);
            FD_ZERO( &readfs);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the return value of `select()`?

Answer (score 4):

All `FD_CLR` and `FD_ZERO` do is reset the fd_set, it doesn't clear the underlying condition.  To do that, you need to `read()` all the data until there isn't any available anymore.

In fact, if you only want to do one fd at a time, you're better off dispensing with the `select()` altogether and just use a blocking `read()` to see when data becomes available.

On a side note, `FD_ZERO` does the same thing as `FD_CLR`, but for all the fds.  If you do one, you don't need the other.

Comment: And the next loop iteration does `FD_SET` again, undoing the `FD_CLR`.

Comment: And don't forget to `fflush(stdout)` after each printf, or you will not see the dot for a long tine.

Answer (score 1):

First, use proper function headers like `int main(void)`. Second, `FD_SET` has an upper limit for storing fds, in other words, not all fds can be monitored with `select`. (`poll` has no such limit.)

Third and finally, in your loop, you only check whether there is data available on the fd, but you never read it. Thus, it is continuing to be available in the next iteration.